# How to get Azure resource count limits and quotas for different resource types at subscription level?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-powershell, quota, azure-rest-api

Working on getting the used count and the capacity by subscription for various Azure resources. This information is to be retrieved either through an API or a Powershell Cmdlet and a historical data about the same information needs to be maintained. Following are the resources we seek to target:

- SQL Servers per subscription
- SQL Databases per server
- Event hub namespaces
- Event hubs per namespace
- Event Grid domains
- Event grid topics

While researching I did not find any API or Powershell Cmdlets in Azure that would return the result in the following manner similar to the storage accounts or virtual machines:

```
{
  "value": [
    {
      "unit": "Count",
      "currentValue": 55,
      "limit": 250,
      "name": {
        "value": "StorageAccounts",
        "localizedValue": "Storage Accounts"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Is there any such way to get the used and the total for the resources listed above in a programmatic manner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> While researching I did not find any API or Powershell Cmdlets in
> Azure that would return the result in the following manner similar to
> the storage accounts or virtual machines: Is there any such way to get
> the used and the total for the resources listed above in a
> programmatic manner?

We have checked Azure Documentation, didnt found any PowerShell cmdlets or rest API to pull resource count limits & quota for a specific resources providers.

Using the below AzureCLI cmdlets we can pull the regional specific limits for resources (Virtual Machines, Network, SQL ,storage Accounts) limits for a particular subscription.

```
az vm list-usage --location <location>
az network list-usages --location <location>
az sql list-usages --location <location>
az storage account show-usage --location <location>
```

After reading multiple documentation , please find the below requested resource limits.

- Here are the SQL Servers per subscription, SQL Databases per server regional limits  you can refer the below image

[image]

- Here are the  Event hub namespaces, Event hubs per namespace regional limits you can refer the below image
  [image]
- Here are the Event Grids regional limits , you can refer [the](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/includes/event-grid-limits.md) below image

[image]

For more information about subscription limits & quota for different resource provider you can refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/azure-subscription-service-limits) documentation.

Comment: This is helpful. Thanks for the information. But is there a way to get the limits/quotas for the event hubs and event grids through the APIs? As I did not find a similar usages API for the two mentioned.

Comment: @kdpatil - No, you cannot get the limits/quotas for the event hubs and event grids through the APIs. We also tried searching for Usage API for Event Hub & Event Grid unfortunately we did not found any.

Comment: Thank you for your response.

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you